# React Navigation - How to calling function from another file and use it on headerRight onPress?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I wonder there's a way to using `headerRight onPress` to doing something like calling `Alert`:

I have a function inside `MyPet.js` with the code :

```
_alert=()=>{
  alert('saving')
}
```

and in `router.js` I have a list of all screen I've used to navigating with a piece of code like :

```js
export const MyPatientStack =  StackNavigator({
  MyPatient: {
    screen: MyPatient,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'My Patient',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <FontAwesome name="wheelchair" size={25} color={tintColor} />,
      headerTitle: 'My Patient',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#8B0000',
      },
      headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton tintColor="#FFF" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />,
// and here I want to call the function of _alert() from MyPet.js
      headerRight: <FontAwesome name='search' size={20} color="#FFF" onPress={_alert()}/>,      
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign:'center',
        flex:1
      },
    }
  }
})
```

Have tried it and the code doesn't find variable `_alert`

How can I do that?

any feedback are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your **Navigation component** has *no reference* to what is in your `Pet.js` component, you may try the following way

Use `navigationOptions` in your `Pet.js` component as

```
// Inside the class
// Since navigationOptions have no access to this parameter of the class, therefore you need to pass them as params
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        const {params}} = navigation.state;
        return {
            headerRight: <FontAwesome name='search' size={20} color="#FFF" onPress={() => params.showAlert()}/> />

        };
    };


 componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            showAlert: this.alertShower
        });
    }

alertShower = () =>  Alert.alert('Success', 'Hello')
```

Comment: it's mean i need to delete the `navigationOptions` in `router.js`?

Comment: Yea, it this `config` is specific to your  `Pet.js component`, you may add the `rest of the configuration` here

Comment: Here's the [heirarchy](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/482) for the `navigationOptions` , `RouteConfigs > Screen Property > StaticNagivatorConfig`